# Is shake also a regular verb?

Tags: verbs, error, irregular-forms

I was listening to a [BBC documentary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p02tssz1) about Putin and heard this:

> ...that shaked one of today's key world leaders

(The sentence is in the first 20 seconds.)

I thought that shake is only conjugated shake/shook/shaken

Anyway, I've found [one source](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/shake.html) where it is considered a regular verb.

Can it be used both as a regular and irregular verb?

Comment: Language is in flux. Come back in 25 years, and you may get a different answer.

Comment: On that Verbix site we find slightly unidiomatic English: `If you think that there's an error in conjugation, check first that you have written correctly the verb to conjugate.` and `This site contains verb conjugations for hundred languages...` When citing a website as an authority, it's good practice to look for independent corroboration on other websites (that aren't simply copycats of the first one).

Comment: You've misheard the podcast.  It doesn't say 'shaked', it says 'shaped'.  It's also in the description below: "Chris Bowlby explores how this experience shaped Putin's career and behaviour today".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker heard the word "shaked" when the actual word spoken by the commentator is "shaped."

Comment: Per so-called standard English, the past tense of *shake* is *shook*. There could be dialects that use *shaked*. Certainly, hundreds of years ago, *shaked* was used, but not exclusively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `to shake` is an irregular verb.

You can compare the usage on [Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shaked%2Cshook&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshaked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshook%3B%2Cc0). `Shook` is used 2000x as often as `shaked`.

Comment: Well it surprises me that it is used incorrectly in a bbc podocast. Anyway, I have edited and added the mp3 in case I missed something and someoione wants to check it

Comment: @Gyonder note that the podcast actually used a different verb altogether: "shaped"